# How do you find the value of $m$ and $n$ if $x+y+z=\frac{m}{\sqrt n}$ given certain conditions on x,y,z?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

**Problem:**
Let $x,y$ and $z$ be real numbers satisfying:
$$x=\sqrt{y^2 - \frac{1}{16}} + \sqrt{z^2 - \frac{1}{16}}$$
$$y=\sqrt{z^2 - \frac{1}{25}} + \sqrt{x^2 - \frac{1}{25}}$$
$$z=\sqrt{x^2 - \frac{1}{36}} + \sqrt{y^2 - \frac{1}{36}}$$

If $x+y+z=\frac{m}{\sqrt n}$, where $m,n \in N$ and $n$ is not divisible by the square of any prime number, then find $m$ and $n$

---

I don't know how to even begin with this question, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This was one of my favorite contest problems growing up! Here's a hint: Suppose triangle $ABC$ satisfies $AB = y$, $AC = z$, and the height from $A$ to $BC$ is $\frac{1}{4}$. Then $BC = \sqrt{y^2 - \frac{1}{16}}+\sqrt{z^2-\frac{1}{16}}$.

Comment: @Joey it is now my favourite contest problem too!!..the symmetry is just amazing!!..but still I am having problem in finding $x$ any help..?? As far as that is concerned,?? My attempt at solution is below..

Comment: @Ashish Gupta can you please confirm if the answer $m=2,n=7$ is correct ??

Comment: @Freelancer Sorry, I was busy. Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @Ashish Gupta are you sure this answer is correct ?? Because I have found a flaw in my answer....but was just waiting for some days to know if my answer is right atleast ...

Comment: @Freelancer Hold on. Let me crosscheck. As far as I remember, the value of m+n was given to be 9, and their separate values weren't given (since the question was to actually find m+n), so I assumed your answer was correct. Let me confirm if it was indeed 9, or I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working on The hint of joey we can make this triangle and take x,y,z as the sides of triangle as follows without the loss of generality....
[image: image 1]
Now just to make a detailed figure ....
[image: image 2]
Just to sum these up ...from the figure we have ...
$$DC=x=\sqrt{y^2 - \frac{1}{16}} + \sqrt{z^2 - \frac{1}{16}}$$
$$BD=y=\sqrt{z^2 - \frac{1}{25}} + \sqrt{x^2 - \frac{1}{25}}$$
$$BC=z=\sqrt{x^2 - \frac{1}{36}} + \sqrt{y^2 - \frac{1}{36}}$$

---

Now note an interesting thing...the triangles $ABC,ACD,ABD$ all have equal sides that is they are congruent so there areas must also be equal ... So

Area of ABC $\frac{1}{2}×z×\frac{1}{6}$ equal to($=$)

area of ACD $\frac{1}{2}×x×\frac{1}{4}$ equal to($=$)

area of ABD $\frac{1}{2}×y×\frac{1}{5}$ equal to ($=$)

That is we can say ... $$\frac{1}{2}×y×\frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{2}×z×\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{2}×x×\frac{1}{4}$$ solving which gives $x+y+z=\frac{15x}{4}$ ...now we just need to find $x$ ...any ideas from your side...

**Edit**: Thanks to the hint of Joey that is also easily done by using herons formula and then equating it to the (area of ACD $=1/2×x×1/4$ ) 
[image: calculation]

After calculating the area by Herons formula as shown in the image you will get Area as $\frac{15x^2\sqrt{7}}{64}$ which is equal to $1/2×x×1/4$ solving this you will get $x=8/15\sqrt{7}$ put this in the value of $x+y+z$ to get answer $2/\sqrt{7}$ so answer is $m=2,n=7$

Comment: Good start. We can solve for $y$ and $z$ in terms of $x$. It would help to know another formula for the area of a triangle.

Comment: @Joey thanks for the help...

Comment: @Ashish is this answer $m=2,n=7$ ..correct.. ??